# In Network Manager how is my current Bitrate greater than the access point MaxBitrate

Tags: linux, wifi-configuration, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I'm working with the D-Bus interface to Network Manager on a custom Linux and I'm trying to find a decent estimate for current connection speed.

If I query the MaxBitrate property of the current connected AccessPoint I get about 270Mbit/s:

```
$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.NetworkManager "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/170" org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint MaxBitrate
u 270000
```

But, if I query the current Bitrate property of the Wifi Device I get a much higher 867Mbit/s:

```
$busctl --no-pager get-property org.freedesktop.NetworkManager "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5" org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless Bitrate
u 866700
```

The latter is supposed to be the correct number by the description but it's higher than the maximum.  What gives?

Is there an interaction between WPA_supplicant, NetworkManager, and Intel Wifi Drivers that causes it to report max speed instead of current?  Is MaxBitrate a per-radio-chain figure?

Comment: I’m seeing a disconnect here. You are inspecting the details of an arbitrary access point. Why do you think it’s the one you’re connected to?

Comment: Because it's the one listed in the Wi-Fi device's ActiveAccessPoint property? Do I need code to demonstrate basic competence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "MaxBitrate" property of AccessPoint objects in NetworkManager is received from wpa_supplicant (according to information in the beacon). As far as I know, it only reports "legacy" rates and does not attempt to account for anything beyond 802.11n (HT).

Meanwhile the "Bitrate" property is received from the actual network interface driver via netlink (not sure if NM gets it directly from the kernel or via wpa_supplicant), similar to `iw wlan0 link`.